# Cache.clean() does NOT work

Tags: python, django, caching, redirect, httprequest

After debugging for many hours, I just give up and ask for your help. Original app isn't as simple as my example, but the problem is the same: problems w/ cache reloading. Original app caches the view and provides another view which should change contents in database and reload cache. I have created demo app which shows that `cache.clean()` does NOT work. Cache is cleaned only when contents in database are expired. Why is that so?

[Demo can be found here.](https://github.com/daGrevis/-DEMO--Cache.clean---does-NOT-work)

Comment: I just looked over your demo and didn't immediately see anything wrong.  Since you are using the db cache, one thing that might help you would be to hook dj_debug_toolbar up.   Might help you see what's going on with both the cache and the db.  If you've never used dj_debug_toolbar it's work checking out.  It's helped me with many issues in the past.  Just a suggestion (not an answer).  Best of luck.

Comment: I'm using debug toolbar. After ton of debugging, just posted working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was browser cache. Browser itself cached the results and that's why I didn't see changes.

Solution was to add `@cache_control(no_cache=True)` in front of cached view. That decorator simply disables browser cache.

Comment: Thanks for posting solution; I will keep that in mind going forward with my own code.